# How do I draw a perfect semicircle between two arbitrary points in Core Graphics?

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I want to draw a [semicircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicircle) between any two arbitrary `CGPoint`s in Core Graphics using Swift. *I want to use Core Graphics and **not** layers.* We would need a flag to decide which of the two possible directions to go in.

For instance, given `CGPoint(x: 8, y: 92)` and `CGPoint(x: 28, y: 66)`, and knowing that we want to draw the semicircle in a clockwise direction and that it is a perfect semicircle, what do I plug in to `addArc` to accomplish this?

#### Gist

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Revolucent/49746731f869d052123ad0eebfbdeeae) for this based on Rob Mayoff's answer below.

Comment: I'd recommend you bust out a pen in paper and start doodling some Cartesian systems :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your given points `p0` and `p1`.

You want to call `graphicsContext.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: radians0, endAngle: radians1, clockwise: clockwise)` and have it draw a semicircle whose endpoints are `p0` and `p1`. Let's figure out what the arguments should be.

- To make a semicircle ending at `p0` and `p1`, `center` must be the midpoint between `p0` and `p1`: `CGPoint(x: 0.5 * (p0.x + p1.x), y: 0.5 * (p0.y + p1.y))`.
- To make the arc end at `p0` and `p1`, `radius` must be the distance from `center` to `p0` (or `p1`), which equals half of the distance between `p0` and `p1`: `0.5 * hypot(p1.x - p0.x, p1.y - p0.y)`.
- `radians0` must be the angle from `center` to `p0`, which equals the angle from `p1` to `p0` (because `center`, `p0`, and `p1` are colinear): `atan2(p1.y - p0.y, p1.x - p0.x)`.
- To make a semicircle, `radians1` must equal `radians0 + .pi`.
- `clockwise` is your “flag to decide which of the two possible directions to go in”.

Comment: Worked a treat.

Comment: Worth making one convenient copy-pasta code block at the end that aggregates all the pieces

Comment: I understood most of this. The part that I was having trouble with was getting the start angle.